# why does GSAP works good on the "mobile view" in Chrome in PC, but messes up on actual mobile phone

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, responsive-design, gsap

So, I'm working a project and in it there is an animation which is triggered when user scrolls to it. this works on PC, and also on the mobile view, on the "device toolbar" in chrome, but there is an issue when viewing it in phone,
This is a part of the gsap code:

```
  roadmap.forEach((item) => {
    const left = item.querySelector(".left")
    const right = item.querySelector(".right")
    gsap.to(left, {
      x:"-100vw",
      duration:1,
      scale:3,
      scrollTrigger:{
        trigger:item,
        start:"top 5%",
        end:"115% 30%",
        ease:"none",
        scrub:false,
        toggleActions:"play none reverse reverse"
      }
    })
    gsap.to(right, {
      x:"100vw",
      duration:1,
      scale:3,
      scrollTrigger:{
        trigger:item,
        start:"top 5%",
        end:"115% 30%",
        ease:"none",
        scrub:false,
        toggleActions:"play none reverse reverse"
      }
    })
  })
```

[image: PC View of the website]

[image: Mobile View of the website]

I've tried to change the start and end field of scrolltrigger, but nothing is changing

Answer (score 0):

Your issue in a real mobile device is very common. The main cause of this issue is the floating address bar of the mobile browser. When you scroll up certain pixels, it will disappear causing increase in heights of HTML elements. And that is why it looks as if the scrollTrigger is all messed up.

A simple work around for this is to refer to **GSAP Documentation** topic `normalizeScroll()`.

If you need any help further, create a minimal GSAP demo in codepen and share the link stating your issue.

Here's the link [normalizeScroll()](https://gsap.com/docs/v3/Plugins/ScrollTrigger/static.normalizeScroll()/)